# docker-machine/vbox shared folder doesn't survive VM restart

Tags: virtualbox, docker

I installed docker-machine and immediately tried to share a folder with the VM it creates.  Here's what I did;

```
# share the folder to the VM
docker-machine stop default
vboxmanage sharedfolder add default --name apt-mirror --hostpath D:/apt-mirror
docker-machine start default
docker-machine env default

# create a mount point within the VM
docker-machine ssh default "sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -d /apt-mirror"

# mount the shared folder within the VM
docker-machine ssh default \
    "echo 'apt-mirror  /apt-mirror   vboxsf   defaults   0   0' \
    | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab ; sudo mount -a"
```

After this I 'docker-machine ssh default', and see everything worked out as expected.

Next, I try a VM restart to make sure everything is going to survive;

```
docker-machine stop default
docker-machine start default
docker-machine env default
```

After this I 'docker-machine ssh default', and find it didn't survive;

- /apt-mirror doesn't exist
- /etc/fstab entry is missing

Still with the ssh session I can execute this to get the mount back;

```
sudo mkdir /apt-mirror
sudo mount -t vboxsf apt-mirror /apt-mirror -o defaults
```

Is there a way to make the initial settings survive restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer based on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32030385/2800918).  Here are all the steps in the form of a bash script which can be run within a docker-machine terminal.

```
#!env bash

: ${NAME:=default}
: ${SHARE:=u:}
: ${MOUNT:=/u}
SCRIPT=/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh

set -x

docker-machine stop $NAME
VBoxManage.exe sharedfolder add $NAME --name u --hostpath 'u:\' --automount 2>/dev/null || :
docker-machine start $NAME
docker-machine env $NAME
docker-machine ssh $NAME 'echo "mkdir -p $MOUNT" | sudo tee $SCRIPT'
docker-machine ssh $NAME 'echo "mount -t vboxsf -o rw,user $SHARE $MOUNT" |  sudo tee -a $SCRIPT'
docker-machine ssh $NAME '$SCRIPT'
```